# How do I find the occurrences of a given word in a sentence?

Tags: c#, optimization

Here is the code for finding the number of occurrence of a given word in a sentence.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str;
    string word;
    int count = 0;
    str = Console.ReadLine();
    word = Console.ReadLine();
    string[] str1 = str.Split(' ','.');
    for (int i = 0; i < str1.Length; i++)
    {
        if (str1[i].Equals(word))
        {                   
            count++;
        }                       
    }
    Console.WriteLine("No of occurrence of a word:" +count);
    Console.ReadLine();

}
```

Is there any best and optimized way to code this..?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a good way to ask here. Did you try anything so far? Show your effort first so people might show theirs. Please read [FAQ] and [ask]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review, and would be better asked on [CodeReview SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4):

```
var occurences = yourString.Split().Count(word => word == wordToMatch);
```

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
var query = from x in "String that contain words".Split().ToList()
            group x by x into G
            let Count = G.Count()
            select new {Value = G.Key, Count = count};
```